# recursive folder reading with java.io.File

Tags: java, matlab, recursion, directory

Currently I create a list of sub folders with this function:

```
% create list of all sub folders
dirs = regexp(genpath(basePath),['[^;]*'],'match');
```

My folders contain however > 100 000 files. This function takes minutes to hours to complete.
The number of folders however is only < 100.

I read that `java.io.File` is magnitudes faster. However how can I use it to read folders recursive?

```
jFile = java.io.File([basePath '*']); %java file object
jPaths = jFile.listFiles;       %java.io.File objects
jNames = jFile.list;            %java.lang.String objects
isFolder = arrayfun(@isDirectory,jPaths); %boolean
dirs = cellstr(char(jNames(~isFolder)));   %cellstr
```

gives me an empty array back.

EDIT:
I tried the following, but the recursion fails because the dirs array is empty after the functions comes back - as if the dirs was a global variable...

```
function [sub] = subfolders (CurrPath,sub)
%------------------------------------------------
jFile = java.io.File(CurrPath); %java file object
jPaths = jFile.listFiles;       %java.io.File objects
jNames = jFile.list;            %java.lang.String objects
isFolder = arrayfun(@isDirectory,jPaths); %boolean
dirs = cellstr(char(jNames(isFolder)))   %cellstr

if nargin == 1
    sub = {};
end

for i = 1:numel(dirs)
    currSubDir = dirs{i};
    if ~isempty(currSubDir)
        sub{end+1} = fixPath([CurrPath '\' currSubDir]);        
        sub = subfolders(sub{end},sub);
    end
end% if
```

Comment: What OS are you working on?

Comment: Hmm, can't you use the new java.nio.file API instead? It is even faster than `File`

Comment: I am using Windows 7, I do not know the nio API, note that I am using Matlab.