# Calling java.io.File(CurrPath) from MATLAB takes a long time

Tags: java, performance, matlab, file

I use this code for getting a list of subdirectories. It is in my code since 2015, but currently takes 50 seconds to execute through a few subfolders.

I once added it, because MATLAB itself was magnitudes slower, see [this previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776523/recursive-folder-reading-with-java-io-file).

```matlab
function [sub] = subfolders (CurrPath,sub)
%------------------------------------------------
jFile = java.io.File(CurrPath); %java file object
jPaths = jFile.listFiles;       %java.io.File objects
if numel(jPaths) > 100
    % sub = {};
    return
end
jNames = jFile.list;            %java.lang.String objects    
isFolder = arrayfun(@isDirectory,jPaths); %boolean
tempFolderList = cellstr(char(jNames(isFolder)));   %cellstr

if nargin == 1
    sub = {};
end

for i = 1:numel(tempFolderList)
    currSubDir = tempFolderList{i};
    if ~isempty(currSubDir)
        sub{end+1} = fixPath([CurrPath '\' currSubDir]);
        % add only if last folder does not contain probe
        if ~stringContains(lower(currSubDir), 'probe') 
            if ~stringContains(lower(currSubDir), 'dg')
                sub = subfolders(sub{end},sub);
            end
        end
    end
end% if

end% functions
```

Is there another and faster way to achieve the same?

Using Dir is not a solution. It takes 60s to execute the code

```matlab
filelist = dir(fullfile(rootdir, '**\*.*'));  %get list of files and folders in any subfolder
folderlist = filelist(filelist.isdir);
```

Comment: In plain java, it would be time to switch to `java.nio`, but I don't know if that is possible via MatLab

Comment: How are these files physically stored: Hard disk? SSD? Network share?

Comment: @deHaar: no I tested that. Not available.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-: NetShare with 30.000 files in the last subfolder. Each java.io.file call takes 2 seconds. With 20 folders this adds up to 50 seconds in total.

Comment: Rereading this and your previous question, do you have a file-tree with 100k+ files, and lots of subdirectories, and want to get the names of all files/(sub-)directories? In that case: why the bother with Java, just use a recursive `dir()` as I said in my last comment. If you want to generate file/directory names and go to them, use `sprintf()` and `cd` or `fullpath()`. All native MATLAB, no need to bother with exotic extensions.

Comment: @Adriaan: I tested `dir`. It takes much too long. If I call this code from home using VPN network it would take 10-100x longer, which means I can eat lunch in the time to find some folders...

Comment: What you're trying to do is impractical... a minute for a recursive directory search over a network, with tens of thousands of folders, is not that long! You'd be better focusing your efforts restructuring your code to just call this a minimal number of times and caching the results in some way, Or refine your search so that you only recurse into the necessary sub-folders.

Comment: It is only 20 folder, of which 10 contains 10k files. So in total the number of files and folders is in the range of 100k, but the number of folders is very low.